# jQuery ajax error function called even on successful request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working on my wordpress site contact form that I want to be sent without page refreshing.
I've managed to get it working, it sends the mail, but then I thought that what if it doesn't succeed, and added the error function. Now, it calls the error function every time, even if it manages to send the mail. 
Here's the code for it:

```
    $("#Submit").click(function () {
    var dataString = $('#knamecontactform').serialize();
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://example.com/form.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "text",
        error: function () {
            $('#messagenotsent').fadeIn(400);
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#knamecontactform')[0].reset();
            $('#messagesent').fadeIn(400);
        }


    });
    return false;

});
```

And the submitform.php:

```
<?php
$to = "mail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message";
$message = 
$_POST['Nimi'] . "\n" .
$_POST['Puhelin'] . "\n" .
$_POST['Sposti'] . "\n" .
$_POST['Tiedot'];
$from = $_POST['Nimi'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo 'Mail sent.';
?>
```

Comment: try to use the `dataType` and also, check if your theme header has leading space before the doctype returned :)

Comment: You must detect the error codes manually just relying on the calling of the error function is not good enogh, yes it is possible for the ajaxerror function to be called on older JQuerys. In fact the document used to have a special note about it but it's gone now.

Comment: As Val says, try and data type and @AnkitGautam His code is actually different for error and success, take a closer look at the classes.

Comment: I added dataType: "html" to it, but it still returns with error. But it sends a mail?

Comment: What does submitForm.php actually echo out to the AJAX function?

Comment: I'll add the submitform.php to the question.

Comment: Try a datatype of "text"

Comment: No change, still fading in the error function.

Comment: Ok lets see what it actually says is the error, the error function takes a signature like `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` do: `console.log(jqXHR);` and add it to your question

Comment: Ummmm... Like replace the current error function with console.log(jqXHR);?

Comment: I changed error:function() {
         $('#messagenotsent').fadeIn(400);
         
}, to error:function() {
         console.log(jqXHR);          
}, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Change it to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log(jqXHR); }` Make sure you press f12 in your browser and have console tab showing

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://scriptit.kotisivut.name/wp/submitform.php. Origin http://wordpress.kotisivut.name is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: HA! Cross domain AJAX...there is your problem, Cross domain AJAX cna be achieved with JSONP but tbh it is normally better to just fix it with a rewrite in wordpress or something to rewrite a same domain url to a different domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to what the commenters above mentioned (your original problem was cross domain AJAX) you may want to consider using the newer (introduced in ver 1.5) jQuery deferred way of handling AJAX events since the error: and success: functions will be deprecated in future versions of jQuery. In addition to being more future-proof I also think it lends a nice bit of readability to your code.

Instead of success use .done and instead of error use .fail. See below for an example.

```
$.ajax({
  //all your regular ajax setup stuff except no success: or error:
 })
 .done( function (data, status) {
     //do whatever you want with the return data upon successful return
 })
 .fail( function (data, status) {
     //do whatever you want with the return data upon error
 });
```

For more info, check out the [jQuery docs on deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: I'll consider this next time :)